# How to use sigsuspend

Tags: c

I have this code, and i have to make the program block repeatedly waiting for a signal. My teacher wants us to use the sigsuspend and masks instead of pause or sleep. I'm not familiar with the sigsuspend or mask, i know that sigsuspend() temporarily replaces the signal mask of the calling process with the mask given by mask and then suspends the process until delivery of a signal whose action is to invoke a signal handler or to terminate a process.
But how do I implement it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

unsigned Conta = 0;

void mypause(int sign)
{
    switch (sign)
    {
        case SIGINT:
            printf("You've pressed ctrl-C\n");
            printf("I'm running waiting for a signal...\n");
            Conta++;
            break;

        case SIGQUIT:
            printf("You've pressd ctrl-\\n");
            printf("Number of times you've pressed CTRL-C: %d", Conta); 
            exit(0);
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    alarm(3);
    printf("I'm Alive\n");

    signal(SIGINT, mypause);
    signal(SIGQUIT, mypause);
    printf("I'm running, waiting for a signal...\n");
    while (1)
    {
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You mask off SIGINT and SIGQUIT, then call sigpause with a mask that allows those two signals again. When sigpause returns though, the signals are masked off again. This lets you check the static variables in a safe way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simple way to get started is to just call `sigsuspend` with an empty mask (i.e., any signal can wake up the program):

```
sigset_t myset;
(void) sigemptyset(&myset);
while (1) {
    (void) printf("I'm running, waiting for a signal...\n");
    (void) sigsuspend(&myset);
}
```

The next step would be to use `sigprocmask` to disable your two handled signals (`SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT`) from occurring other than when you're waiting from them in `sigsuspend`. Then you would use the “old mask” obtained from `sigprocmask` instead of the empty mask when suspending.

Comment: This does not appear to work on OS X. Placing a `printf` after the call to `sigsuspend` with an empty set never prints. (Or I am misunderstanding how to use `sigsuspend` based on this answer).

Comment: @jww Well, `sigsuspend` is supposed to _suspend_ the program, so it's not supposed to execute anything after _unless you send a signal_ to it.

Answer (score 9):

The [GNU libc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigsuspend.html) description seems clear and thorough:

> Function: int sigsuspend (const sigset_t *set)
>
> This function replaces the process's signal mask with set and then suspends the 
>   process until a signal is delivered whose action is
>   either to terminate the process or invoke a signal handling function.
>   In other words, the program is effectively suspended until one of the
>   signals that is not a member of set arrives.
>
> If the process is woken up by delivery of a signal that invokes a handler function, 
>   and the handler function returns, then sigsuspend
>   also returns.
>
> The mask remains set only as long as sigsuspend is waiting. The function sigsuspend 
>   always restores the previous signal mask when it
>   returns.
>
> The return value and error conditions are the same as for pause.
>
> With sigsuspend, you can replace the pause or sleep loop in the
>   previous section with something completely reliable:
>
> ```
>  sigset_t mask, oldmask;
>
>  ...
>
>  /* Set up the mask of signals to temporarily block. */
>  sigemptyset (&mask);
>  sigaddset (&mask, SIGUSR1);
>
>  ...
>
>  /* Wait for a signal to arrive. */
>  sigprocmask (SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask);
>  while (!usr_interrupt)
>    sigsuspend (&oldmask);
>  sigprocmask (SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);
> ```
>
> This last piece of code is a little tricky. The key point to remember
>   here is that when sigsuspend returns, it resets the process's signal
>   mask to the original value, the value from before the call to
>   sigsuspend—in this case, the SIGUSR1 signal is once again blocked. The
>   second call to sigprocmask is necessary to explicitly unblock this
>   signal.
>
> One other point: you may be wondering why the while loop is necessary
>   at all, since the program is apparently only waiting for one SIGUSR1
>   signal. The answer is that the mask passed to sigsuspend permits the
>   process to be woken up by the delivery of other kinds of signals, as
>   well—for example, job control signals. If the process is woken up by a
>   signal that doesn't set usr_interrupt, it just suspends itself again
>   until the “right” kind of signal eventually arrives.
>
> This technique takes a few more lines of preparation, but that is
>   needed just once for each kind of wait criterion you want to use. The
>   code that actually waits is just four lines.

Comment: While this answer is a lot better than Arkku ones, it in general not correct to do the second sigprocmask after sigsuspend returned. The idea is to block SIGUSR1 before it can happen, then enter sigsuspend and wait for pending signals (signals that happened but which are blocked). sigsuspend also unblocks those signals so that when they happen(ed) a signal handler will be called before sigsuspend returns. In other words, sigsuspend allows for synchronous handling of signals: when a signal is received it is blocked but queued until sigsuspend is called and *then* acted upon.

Answer (score 1):

-By using sigsuspend() API, a process can suspend its execution until any one of
the signal is delivered from set of signals.

- The clean and reliable way to wait for a signal is to block it and
  then use sigsuspend.
- By using sigsuspend in a loop, one can wait for certain kind of
  signals while allowing other kind of signals to be handled by their
  handler.
- It allows process to suspend its execution until the receipt of one
  the signal which is is not present in the set pointed by mask.
- Syntax: int sigsuspend(sigset_t *mask);
- It temporarily replaces the process current mask with a new mask and
  is restored once the handler for the signal returns.
- Since sigsuspend() suspends threads execution indefinitely, there is
  no successful completion return value and return -1 on failure.

This program makes sure that SIGKILL and SIGTERM
signal is blocked when the program execute in critical section
and resumes execution once SIGINT is signaled and its
corresponding signal handler is executed */

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #include <errno.h>
     #include <signal.h>


     int cs = 0;
     int value = 5;

     /* This is the function called on receipt of signal(cntl+c) */
     void sig_handler (int sig)
     {
        printf("\n This is signal handler for signal %d\n", sig);
        cs =1;
     }

    int main()
    {
        struct sigaction act;
        act.sa_handler = sig_handler;
        sigemptyset (&act.sa_mask);
        sigaddset (&act.sa_mask, SIGPIPE);
        act.sa_flags = 0;

        sigset_t sig_term_kill_mask;
        sigaddset (&sig_term_kill_mask, SIGTERM);
        sigaddset (&sig_term_kill_mask, SIGKILL);

        sigaction (SIGINT, &act, NULL);

        /* Critical section */
        value++;
        printf ("\n Value is %d\n", value);
        while (cs == 0)
            sigsuspend (&sig_term_kill_mask);

        printf("\n Return from suspended successful\n");
        int ret = sigismember (&act.sa_mask, SIGPIPE);
        if (ret)
            printf("\n Old Mask that is SIGPIPE is restored after return from sigsuspend\n");
        else
            printf("\n Old Mask that is SIGPIPE failed to restored after return from sigsuspend\n");

         return 0; }
```

**Output:**

gcc sigsuspend.c

./a.out

Value is 6
^C
This is signal handler for signal 2

Return from suspended successful

Old Mask that is SIGPIPE is restored after return from sigsuspend

Comment: uh, SIGKILL can't be blocked.